# Choose and delete random word from array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, random

I'm trying to remake a wordgame I made in Python in Javascript. I'm having trouble to do some basic things.

The script should load a list of words and when you click the button, it should show a random word from the list. I tried several ways and I did not come further than the index number showing up and not refreshing when the button was clicked again.

So my question at this stage would be: how do I choose a random array item with clicking, and removing it after so it doesn't appear a second time when you click again. I do want to add a time limit of showing the words and a TTS afterwards, but that will come later.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Aliyah's dictee spel</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="header">
    <h1>Hej! Velkommen til Aliyahs diktee!</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="Random_word">
        <h2 id="Empty">Click new word to start</h2>
        <button id="refresh_word">new word</button>

    </div>
    <input type="text" id="input1" />
    <input type="submit" name="ok" value="ok"/>
    <script>
        
    var words = ["test1", "test2", "test3"];
    var wordsCorrect = 0;
    var wordsWrong = 0;

    newWord(words)
    {
        var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length);
        document.getElementById("Empty").innerHTML = random;
    };
    document.getElementById("refresh_word").addEventListener("click", newWord());

    

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `()` behind a function reference always calls the function right then and there.

Answer (score 2):

Replace:

```js
document.getElementById("refresh_word").addEventListener("click", newWord());
```

with:

```js
document.getElementById("refresh_word").addEventListener("click", () => newWord(words));
```

You're also missing the `function` keyword in front of the `newWord` declaration and also `words[random]` instead of just `random` which is an index.

```js
var words = ["test1", "test2", "test3"];
var wordsCorrect = 0;
var wordsWrong = 0;

function newWord(words)
{
  var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length);
  document.getElementById("Empty").innerHTML = words[random];
  words.splice(random, 1);
};
document.getElementById("refresh_word").addEventListener("click", () => newWord(words));
```

```html
<div id="header">
<h1>Hej! Velkommen til Aliyahs diktee!</h1>
</div>
<div id="Random_word">
  <h2 id="Empty">Click new word to start</h2>
  <button id="refresh_word">new word</button>
</div>
<input type="text" id="input1" />
<input type="submit" name="ok" value="ok"/>
```

Comment: It should even be `() => newWord(words)`. The event does not contain the words, therefore it should be passed by calling function.

Comment: Yes indeed thanks for pointing out

Comment: And then add `words.splice(random, 1)` after setting the DOM to complete the question of "removing it after so it doesn't appear a second time when you click again". Then you "just" need to take care of the case when the array is empty.

Comment: or just remove the `words` parameter and use the global variable.  given the OP presumably also wants the correct/wrong counts and these are global, it doesn't seem worth just passing `words`

Comment: Thanks guys! I'm a total noob, I managed to make a nice working one in Python, I just didn't understand Javascript, but this helped me a lot!